# Unresolved import 'azure.storage.blob' when trying to use Python library azure-storage-blob

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

Following this URL as example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#list-the-blobs-in-a-container

I'm trying to use Python library, azure-storage-blob to extract the file names of the files stored in blob. I already installed all required package as followed using conda as I am using virtual environment in anaconda.

conda install -c anaconda azure
conda install -c conda-forge azure-storage-blob
conda install -c conda-forge azure-nspkg

But my code won't compile with error message Unresolved import 'azure.storage.blob'
I also have an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'

But, I already installed these packages. Could you please let me know how I can resolve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
    import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient, __version__

try:
    print("Azure Blob Storage v" + __version__ + " - Python sample")
except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:')
    print(ex)

# Retrieve the connection string for use with the application. The storage
# connection string is stored in an environment variable on the machine
# running the application called AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING. If the environment variable is
# created after the application is launched in a console or with Visual Studio,
# the shell or application needs to be closed and reloaded to take the
# environment variable into account.
connect_str = os.getenv('AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING')

# Create BlobServiceClient object
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)

containers_list = blob_service_client.list_containers

print(containers_list)
```

[image: unresolved]

[image: modulenotfound]

Answer (score 1):

I found out that with visual studio code, this is not really an error. As, when I tried to run with command python <script.py>, my script actually executed. Therefore, installing these packages are enough to use these libraries:
conda install -c anaconda azure
conda install -c conda-forge azure-storage-blob