# Error import could not be resolved with Python

Tags: python, azure, pip, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I'm trying to use Azure-storage-blob with Python importing with

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
```

and installed in my .venv with *pip install azure-storage-blob* and required in requirements.txt with *azure-storage-blob*
This is my pip list of the environment

```
Package                   Version
------------------------- ---------
adal                      1.2.7
azure-common              1.1.28
azure-core                1.21.1
azure-cosmos              4.2.0
azure-functions           1.8.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg 3.0.1
azure-mgmt-nspkg          3.0.2
azure-mgmt-scheduler      2.0.0
azure-mgmt-search         2.1.0
azure-mgmt-servicebus     0.5.3
azure-mgmt-servicefabric  0.2.0
azure-mgmt-signalr        0.1.1
azure-mgmt-subscription   0.2.0
azure-mgmt-trafficmanager 0.50.0
azure-mgmt-web            0.35.0
azure-nspkg               3.0.2
azure-storage-blob        12.9.0
azure-storage-common      2.1.0
backcall                  0.2.0
certifi                   2021.10.8
cffi                      1.15.0
charset-normalizer        2.0.9
click                     8.0.4
colorama                  0.4.4
cryptography              36.0.1
cycler                    0.11.0
debugpy                   1.5.1
decorator                 5.1.0
entrypoints               0.3
fonttools                 4.28.5
idna                      3.3
ipykernel                 6.6.0
ipython                   7.30.1
isodate                   0.6.1
itsdangerous              2.1.0
jedi                      0.18.1
Jinja2                    3.0.3
jupyter-client            7.1.0
jupyter-core              4.9.1
msrest                    0.6.21
msrestazure               0.6.4
nest-asyncio              1.5.4
numpy                     1.21.5
oauthlib                  3.2.0
packaging                 21.3
pandas                    1.3.5
parso                     0.8.3
pickleshare               0.7.5
Pillow                    8.4.0
pip                       22.0.3
prompt-toolkit            3.0.24
pycparser                 2.21
pydocumentdb              2.3.5
Pygments                  2.11.0
PyJWT                     2.3.0
pymongo                   4.0.1
pyparsing                 3.0.6
python-dateutil           2.8.2
python-dotenv             0.19.2
pytz                      2021.3
pywin32                   303
pyzmq                     22.3.0
requests                  2.26.0
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1
```

But im getting **Import "azure.storage.blob" could not be resolved**
How can I solve this problem??

UPDATE: It just don't work in my .venv and under lib/site-package/azure there is not "storage" folder

Comment: Are you sure that your environment is activated when you are running your code?

Comment: Yes, in the terminal I see (.venv), it is active.

Comment: And are you getting "Import "azure.storage.blob" could not be resolved" when you are actually running your code, or is it only a hint given by your IDE and does your code execute correctly? Reason I'm asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141052/unresolved-import-azure-storage-blob-when-trying-to-use-python-library-azure-s

Comment: When I run my code it say ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'.

In fact in my .venv under Lib/site-package/azure I don't see "storage" folder, but when try to install azure-storage-blob it say that the it is installed

Answer (score 0):

Try either of the following ways to resolve `Import "azure.storage.blob" could not be resolved` error:

**1.** If you are using visual studio code, try following command to install `azure-storage-blob`:

```
conda install -c anaconda azure conda install -c conda-forge azure-storage-blob
```

**2.** Uninstall older version of  `azure-storage-blob’ and reinstall:`   pip uninstall azure`and`pip uninstall azure-storage`

Reinstall at the specific path:

`cdd .venv`

`pip install azure-storage –upgrade`

References: [Unresolved import 'azure.storage.blob' when trying to use Python library azure-storage-blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141052/unresolved-import-azure-storage-blob-when-trying-to-use-python-library-azure-s) , [How to import Azure BlobService in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558463/how-to-import-azure-blobservice-in-python) and [Install Azure Python api on linux: importError: No module named storage.blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787450/install-azure-python-api-on-linux-importerror-no-module-named-storage-blob)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone I solved recreating .venv